# Editing post - Show preview of title

Tags: feature-request, edits

When editing a post I'd like the preview below the editing textarea to also preview the title of the post. I have two reasons for wanting this.

**Attention to title**

I have a tendancy to focus my attention to much on the body of the message. I've found myself editing away a type-o in the body, while the same type-o remains in the title, since I can't see it in the preview and the title is edited in a separate field.

**Editing process**

From time to time my editing process looks like this:

1. Come across post that needs edit.
2. Click "edit".
3. After some editing I want to review the original look of the post.

At step three I am actually stuck. Currently there is (to my knowledge) no way to view the original post or even a link that I could open in a new tab to view the original post. Adding a preview of the title would allow me to ctrl+click the title link to review the post as it was in a new tab. Now I often have to open a new SO homepage and try to browse my way back to the post, or just copy the body of my edit and do a browser-back to review the post. And if I'm copying the body, well then any of my changes to the title are discarded when I re-edit and paste.

For me these improvements would (hopefully) make me focus more on title-corrections, and ease my editing process.

Comment: Agreed, I have similar problems. After editing the title, I have no idea what the original title was and if it was actually an improvement.

Comment: I always forget to edit the title when fixing up a post (and then have to re-edit), and I bet this would fix it for me. Re: your second point, can you not just right click > new tab the title above the editing area?

Comment: Which title were you thinking of? [Standard editing view](http://i.imgur.com/cf9WdgV.png) (I want to open OP)

Comment: It already shows the edited title. It just shows it at the top of the page instead of in the preview box. Also, you seem to change your focus. Is the feature request to show the *original* or the *edited* title?

Comment: @Anonymous, where at the top? You mean the edit field? See my screenshot in comment. I see you point with the "change of focus", but my intention was always to show the *edited* title. Having the title previewed just happens to serve an additional purpose related to my editing habbits.

Comment: Oh, you are referring to *asking a question* instead of actually *editing*? You may want to make that clear in the question because it may be confusing.

Comment: @Anonymous, no this is for editing. I'm starting to wonder if <2000 users see this differently than >2000 users. Does my screenshot look unfamiliar?

Comment: I just tested it and yes, there is a difference.  Here is a comparison: http://prntscr.com/477q8b

Comment: Wow. You got what I want! Sub 2000 problems, clearly. Thanks @Anonymous.