# User doesn't edit an answer but instead deletes it and creates a new one

Tags: support, specific-answer

Please see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25702739/217408).

I'm just curios what can cause this behavior because I never had this.

The user states that when he edits an answer he is redirected to a new page and can't see the question anymore.

Comment: @Anonymous: I fail to see how this is a dupe of that one. This concerns another user whom doesn't get the *inline editor* when editing their answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Look specifically at my comment here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266992/editing-post-show-preview-of-title#comment68841_266992 Users without editing privileges are shown a completely different view from others. I may be wrong, but it looks like the same problem to me...

Comment: Inline editing is 2000+ only for some reason, He will get directed to this page http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25702739/edit

Comment: @Anonymous: the user has editing privileges *for their own posts*. And they are logged in, because posting a new answer worked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Hmmm, I just tested on ServerFault (as I have low rep there and answers) and it didn't open inline

Comment: @MartinSmith: ah, failure on my part; incognito window fail.

Comment: @MartinSmith: right, you get a separate edit page, but the *question is at the top*; you can drag down the divider; you can see the question on that page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. <2000 is a while back and I didn't remember it was different then.